# JS debugging not hitting correctly after adding line of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, wickedpicker

I'm seeing a super odd issue. When I added the following code, the Chrome/Firefox debugger gets out of sync, meaning it seems to hit on comments and white spaces.

```
$('#new-show-time').wickedpicker({
  now: moment().format("HH:mm"),
  title: 'Select Time',
   twentyFour: false,
  showSeconds: false
  });

$('#new-air-break-time').wickedpicker({
  now: moment().format("HH:mm"),
  title: 'Select Time',
   twentyFour: false,
  showSeconds: false
  });
```

Even stranger, if I comment the code out I get a console error that syntax is incorrect. I have to cut the code from the file for it to work.

Anyone have an idea of what might be happening here?

Comment: is this the only code in the file, or could the syntax error be coming from another line of code?

Comment: No, there is a lot of other JS in the file, but once I add the lines above, the debugger gets all confused. Once I remove those lines, it works again.

Comment: so it throws a syntax error even if that's the only thing in the tile and it's commented out.

Comment: Yes, it throws an exception when the line is commented, and indicates the error is on the wrong line. So if the code is on line 106, when I comment it out, the error shows it's on line 107, even though there is nothing there.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's just so weird. I want to make sure we're on the same page. You're saying that there's a syntax error being thrown, even when the code above is the _only_ code in the file, and that code is commented out; meaning that there is essentially nothing to parse, but it still somehow throws and error? // Can you please just post the full file...?

Comment: Well, there is a JS file that has about 2000 lines in it. I added the above two lines and the debugging went haywire. I removed the lines and it worked again.

The compile error happens if I comment out the two lines, but leave the remaining 2000 in place. If I remove the two lines, the compile works.

It's super strange, I've never seen anything like this. Especially since it breaks JS debugging in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: your syntax looks fine. could it have something to do with the way you're calling `moment()`?

Comment: I use moment() in many places, but that's a good thought, I'll try changing it to a JS date function.

Comment: I was just thinking maybe setting it to a variable and then passing the variable. Realistically that shouldn't matter, but in situations like this you have to try some weird things sometimes.

Comment: My solution was kind of a stupid workaround. I ended up moving all calls to the WickedPicker into a file of their own and just referencing them. It worked, but doesn't tell me why it was doing what it did.